# Find between patterns and process between patterns

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file format like below,

```
####################### FILE Content ###################

Path 1
AND cell
OR1 cell
BUFF1 cell
OR2 cell
Ends

Path 2
OR1 cell
BUFF1 cell
AND1 cell
AND2 cell
BUFF2 cell
OR2 cell
Ends

Path 3
AND1 cell
AND2 cell
AND3 cell
OR1 cell
Ends

##########################################
```

I need output like below:

```
Path 1 - BUFF* count 1

Path 2 - BUFF* count 2

Path 3 - No BUFF
```

By using sed i can first get the Pattern to Pattern like.
`sed -n '/Path/,/Ends/p'` 
Further to get the Ouput after that, i need your expertise help.
can someone help me please.

*Thanks GB*

Answer (score 2):

You might use `awk` and use patterns to check if you are between Path followed by a digit and Ends.

When it matches `Ends` print the current Path you are in and the count of BUFF's.

Then reset the variables seen and buff.

```
awk '
/^Path [0-9]+/{seen=1; buff=0; path=$0; next}
{
  if(seen && $1 ~ /^BUFF[0-9]+$/){++buff;}
}
{
  if(seen && $1 ~ /^Ends$/){
    print path " - " (buff ? "BUFF* count " buff : "No BUFF")
    seen=0; buff=0    
  }
}
' file
```

Output

```
Path 1 - BUFF* count 1
Path 2 - BUFF* count 2
Path 3 - No BUFF
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, attempts; please try following code in `awk`.

```
awk '
/Path/{
  if(count){
     print pathVal," - BUFF* count "(count?count:"NO BUFF")
  }
  found=""
  count=0
  pathVal=$0
  next
}
/BUFF/{
  count++
}
/Ends/{
  found=1
}
END{
  if(found){
     print pathVal," - BUFF* count "(count?count:"NO BUFF")
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '             ##Starting awk program from here.
/Path/{           ##If line contains Path then do following.
  if(count){      ##If count is set then do following.
     print pathVal," - BUFF* count "(count?count:"NO BUFF") ##Printing output with variables and string as per OP need here.
  }
  found=""        ##Nullifying found here.
  count=0         ##Setting 0 to count here.
  pathVal=$0      ##Setting current line to pathVal here.
  next            ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
/BUFF/{           ##Checking if BUFF is found in line then increase count with 1 here.
  count++
}
/Ends/{           ##Checking if Line contains Ens then setting found to 1 here.
  found=1
}
END{              ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  if(found){      ##If found is set then print as per OP requirement values with strings.
     print pathVal," - BUFF* count "(count?count:"NO BUFF")
  }
}
'  Input_file     ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: But of course this is great. I spent some time putting it together, so I thought lets post it. I forgot the `next` call so I added it.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & shell):

```
sed -n '/^Path.*/{s//& - BUFF* count $((0))/;h}
        /^BUFF/{g;s/(0/(0+1/;h}
        /^Ends/{g;/+/!s/-.*/- No BUFF/;s/^Path.*/echo "&"/ep;z;h}' file
```

For each `Path` make a copy, add some text and initialise a counter.

For each `BUFF` increment the counter.

For each `Ends`, replace the added text with a different text if the counter has not been incremented. Wrap the whole message in double quotes and echo the result by way of evaluating the result, then clean up.

N.B. The counter will be interpolated within the double quotes of the echo command.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk` in paragraph mode and using `gsub()` function for getting how many times `/BUFF[[:digit:]]+/` appears:

```
awk -v RS= -v FS='\n' '
   $1 ~ /Path/ && $NF == "Ends"  && /BUFF/{
           n=gsub(/BUFF[[:digit:]]+/,"&");print $1 " - BUFF* count " n}
   $1 ~ /Path/ && $NF == "Ends"  && !/BUFF/{
           print $1 " - No BUFF"}
' file
Path 1 - BUFF* count 1
Path 2 - BUFF* count 2
Path 3 - No BUFF
```